# How do I display a string in an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I MUCKED UP MY PREVIOUS EXPLANATION, ok, I'll try again

I have a button, and a text field, you enter text into the text field, press the button, and it's meant to take you to another page and display the entered text, buuut

[image]

Ok, so, I want the underlined message to the left (the one with the skinny arrow pointing from it) to be the variable getting called in android:text="@string/message" but, android:text="@string/message" is instead calling it from the strings.xml which has `<string name="message">words</string>` so no matter what I enter into the text field, the second page will always say, "words"

I really hope that makes sense Dx

Comment: I don't understand your question. `message` is already a `String`.

Comment: Sorry I'm terrible at explaining, um, when I do @strings/message I get the error message "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@strings/message')

Comment: A few things don't make sense here. a) Your `message` variable already is a `String`. b) You saying you're having issues with a button - there's no button in your code? c) You're creating your `TextView` in code, but never doing anything with it. Do you want to show the content of the `message` string inside some `TextView` you've defined in your layout xml?

Comment: Shall I just put in everything Dx

Comment: `@strings/message` is looking for an entry in your `strings.xml` whose name is `message`, like this: `<string name="message">Some message</string>`. Your entry has name `entered_message`.

Comment: I changed that when I copy and pasted it into here because it seemed a better variable, but I forgot to change it in the @strings part, I changed it in eclipse just now too, so ignore that

Comment: I don't know if anyone saw it but your main problem is that you were trying to setup your layout before you called `this.setContent(int layout_id)`. You were setting the content in the last line of your `onCreate()`. `this.setContent(int layout_id)` should always be the second line of your activity right after your super call.

Comment: My layout is all good, I just need to know how to use my entered message, really, I have no problems with my layout or anything, the page turns over just fine, it's just, I don't know how to declare the string variables using other variables, a mod changed my question so now it doesn't relate to what I want to know xD

Comment: Since you've changed the question I think I now understand what you want to do so I have edited my answer below. Hopefully that is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confusing question. But if you want the string variable to be the string from your xml file you should do the following:

```
String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.entered_message);
```

However the way you're doing things here seems very strange. But without knowing exactly what you're trying to do I can't be sure.

Since you've changed your question I think I know what you want to do so I've edited my answer. As John mentioned in his post the first thing you need to do is call `setContentView` directly after the call to `super.onCreate`. This means you will be able to access the TextView from your xml layout and change its text to the text which has been passed into your activity. I will give an example below.

Firstly you need to add an id to your text view in the layout file called activity_display_message.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/message"/>
```

Then, if I've understood what you want to do correctly your `onCreate` method contain the following:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

Comment: Oh, yes, that might work, I'll try it, although, I'm not really wanting the entered_message there at all, it's simply there because if I don't have it I get an error, I'll try make my explanation clearer

Comment: Framge91 has given a good example. You should use his method 2. Then if you need to refer to your TextView in code you can do `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`

Answer (score 2):

```
String entered_message = getRessources().getString(R.string.entered_message);
```

However your String is empty. Change it to:

```
<string name="entered_message">Here some text</string>
```

Furthermore you don't add the TextView to your Layout. You have two choices:

(1): Add the View to the current Layout by for example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content)
layout.addView(textView);
```

(In your main xml file the layout should have: android:id="@+id/content").

(2): Add the TextView directly to your XML file and assign the string inside of the xml (better approach):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/content">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/entered_message"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused on exactly *what* your problem is here but you have a couple problems if you want your `TextView` to display the message. This line here

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

will create a new `TextView`, not reference the one you have in your xml. And it won't show because you haven't added it to your `contentView`. So, when you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);` what will be shown is what is in `activity_display_message`. If you want to access that `View` then you need to give it an `id` in your xml file and access it with `findViewById()`. So give it an `id`

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv1"   // give it an id here
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/entered_message" />
```

then access it **after** calling `setContentView(...)`

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);  // reference it here with the id you gave it in the xml

}
```

Now that you have referenced the `TextView`, you can call `setText()`, `setTextSize()`, etc.. if need be.

I'm not exactly sure what `String` you want where so its hard to give much more help without a better explanation. But note that

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

will assign the `message` variable to whatever is passed in your `Intent` from the calling `Activity`.

Comment: I completely redid my question, hope it makes more sense

Comment: This is the correct answer to populate your `TextView` with the content of the `message` String, as underlined in the left image.

Comment: @Darktiger138 did you try my answer? This should work for what you are describing as expected results. You are always showing the same message because, as my answer says, you aren't actually adding that `TextView` to your `layout`. You create it but never add it to the `layout`. So when you call `setContentView()` as you are, it is loading the `TextView` from your xml and the `String` that you set there with `@string/balh`. Try this, I'm pretty sure this is what you want from what you are describing.

Comment: I'm trying it, but, if I don't have the setText() and setTextSize() then I get two error messages on the lines String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); and TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); because I don't use the variables anywhere, but if I do put the setText() and setTextSize() then I get error messages on them

Comment: You aren't getting an error message. You are getting a warning saying that they aren't being used. Use my code and add `tv.setText(message);` after `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a layout, it looks like you already did:

**layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now you create your string value:

**string.xml**

```
<string name="entered_message">Hello everyone!!</string>
```

Now you have to get the TextView in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    //^^ do this first!!

    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //^^ dont do this

    // do this:
    String message = this.getString(R.string.entered_message);
    TextView textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.root);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

and there you go! That all should show the text on the screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should `this.getResources().getString(R.id.entered_message);` At least thats how its done for other resources, maybe its different with Strings but I'm not sure why it would be!

Comment: Strings are different, you can do `this.getResources()...` but because Strings are so often pulled from the resources the Activity.getString(int id) does the same thing. It is a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="entered_message">Hello everyone!!</string>
```

Now you have to get the TextView in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    //^^ do this first!!

    // do this:

    TextView textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.root);

    textView.setText(R.string.entered_message);
}
```